# XmlSerializer exception with large amount of objects

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am storing `DLL` information into the following class:

```
[XmlRoot("Modules")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Module))]
public class Modules : List<Module> {}

[XmlType("Module")]
public class Module
{
  [XmlIgnore()]
  public bool Selected { get; set; }
  [XmlElement()]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [XmlElement()]
  public string Version { get; set; }
  [XmlElement()]
  public byte[] Binary;
}
```

When I serialize a handful of `Module` classes in the list using the following code, it is fine.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Modules));
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
  serializer.Serialize(sw, ugModules.DataSource);
}
```

However, my problem comes when within the list, I have 113 items - now obviously that is quite a lot of data with the binary.

I am getting a `System.OutOfMemory` exception, I seem to remember having to increase a threshold of some sort but I can't find the correct property or method for what exactly I have to change.

I am serializing this to XML to pass the XML into SQL and then store the information within a table, just for a bit of scope on what exactly I am doing.

How do I get around the exception? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are using strings and writing at once. They grows exponentially in memory. Try using something that can create buffer stream and do ongoing write instead of writing at once.

Comment: @Guanxi I understand what you mean, however I can't see a method on the serializer which allows this?

Comment: You might want to try a System.IO.MemoryStream instead. Also look at your encoding. If you don't need to use a double byte character set for the XML, then you can cut the space in half by using a single byte character set.